# Match Postgis SRID with Redis' spherical model?

Tags: postgresql, redis

I'm using Postgres (with PostGIS) and I have geometry columns which have the SRID of 4326. In my stack, Redis is acting as a cache and holds the location data using [it's geo functionality](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd), specifically, let's say I have a location in Postgres like so:

```
INSERT INTO locations(geom) VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(40.7547 -73.9614)', 4326)) RETURNING 'id';
```

Then the object gets added to Redis:

```
redis> GEOADD someId -73.9614 40.7547
```

The question is, because Redis uses a totally spherical model of the globe, is it beneficial to use a similarly spherical model SRID for postgres? I found [EPSG:4047](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/unspecified-datum-based-upon-the-grs-1980-authalic-sphere/) which is a sphere.

Are there time, accuracy, or other benefits or pitfalls I'm not seeing?

Comment: Thank you @ThingumaBob. I think I was needlessly trying to find an optimization that is not possible or realistic, appreciate the insight. If you want to pop that into a question, id happily accept it. thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! ...I kinda simply copied my comment as an answer. One might expect some additional effort, but there is not much to add unless I would write a lengthy explanation of spatial references and such...come join us at [gis.se] for some of those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the data in EPSG:4326, if all computations are to be done in the Redis environment it won't matter; you cannot pass in spatial reference information, and Redis seems to assume the WGS84 based *(Spherical) Web Mercator* projection ('seems' because they state to use a wrongly assigned and deprecated EPSG code for it...), at least for their indexing implementation.

The distance calculation via Haversines is unaffected by changing between those reference systems (and the CRS that Redis uses); the formulae work independent from any spatial reference other than the spherical radius.